# Git - Cherry pick a single commit for pull request

Tags: git, github

I might not have the terminology down yet.

I made file to be added to a open project on git.
I forked the project.
I made some changes and my last commit is the file I want to request to the project and not the small changes I made before hand.

When I go to github site and make pull request, I get all the commits before the one I want (which is last one of a file).

I don't want to submit all of the other commits, because I don't think it's necessary for the project. Just my own changes.

What do I do?
Should I just make another res, or attach the file singularly and submit?

Comment: Just a heads-up, this doesn't work as described by SLaks. Even though I've cherry-picked the last merged commit to master, the PR still wants to aggregate the last 31 commits I've made to origin:master since the last large PR I filed. I've now tried about a dozen ways to cherry-pick a single commit to create a PR with, all without success. 100% failure. I've tried resetting the branch to the last commit, creating a feature branch with just that last commit, creating a diff/patch and PR'ing that, no luck. In every single case, it wants to create the PR with the last 31 commits I've made to the

Answer (score 97, accepted):

You need to create a fresh branch from the remote HEAD, cherry-pick the commit to that branch, push the branch to your repo on GitHub, then create a pull request.

```
git checkout -b mybranch
git fetch upstream
git reset --hard upstream/master
git cherry-pick <commit-hash>
git push origin mybranch:mybranch
```

Comment: Worked perfectly thank you!  How do you recommended doing pull request in the future? Should I just keep everything local and only commit to my fork github res the ones that I want to pull request?

Comment: @user3590149: Yes, and make a separate branch for each pull request.  If you want to, you can push non-pull-request changes to a different branch.

Comment: Seems to be what I'm looking for. I don't know at all what I'm doing but... here comes the cargo cult! :)

Comment: After cherry-picking from a pull request, what will the pull request's status be? will it still be open or will it be merged?

Comment: `git fetch upstream` resulted in an error `fatal: 'upstream' does not appear to be a git repository`. I was able to use `git fetch origin master` and then `git reset --hard origin/master`.  Alternatively you could set your upstream before step 2 by typing `git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master mybranch` assuming your remote (origin) branch is called "master" and your new local branch is called "mybranch" as show above.

Answer (score 1):

As I'm doing this a lot, and had to look up this answer a few times, I put SLaks answer into a little batch file. This is for Windows / CMD but should be trivial to port to Linux, Mac or PowerShell. As I usually do several commits, each being one pull request, I also added switching back to the master branch.

```
@echo off

REM Idea from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25955822/git-cherry-pick-a-single-commit-for-pull-request

set BRANCH_NAME=%1
set COMMIT_HASH=%2

IF %BRANCH_NAME%.==. GOTO NoBranchName
IF %COMMIT_HASH%.==. GOTO NoCommitId

git checkout -b %BRANCH_NAME%
git fetch upstream
git reset --hard upstream/master
git cherry-pick %COMMIT_HASH%
git push origin %BRANCH_NAME%:%BRANCH_NAME%
git switch master

GOTO End

:NoBranchName
  ECHO No branch name given. Usage: add-pull-request.bat BRANCH_NAME COMMIT_HASH
GOTO End

:NoCommitId
  ECHO No commit id given. Usage: add-pull-request.bat BRANCH_NAME COMMIT_HASH
GOTO End

:End
```

One obvious improvement would be first picking up the current branch and then use that in the last line but that's something I didn't need and it would make the whole thing significantly more complex.