# GitHub - how to create two pull requests from one fork

Tags: git, github

I have forked an open source repository, written thousands of lines of code on my fork and created a pull request on the original project.

In the meantime I have fixed another bug totally unrelated to my first pull request. I'd like to create a second pull request just for this bug which does not contain any of the work in my first pull request.

Can it be done without me forking the repository again?

Comment: I think this question would be useful to you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25955822/git-cherry-pick-a-single-commit-for-pull-request

Comment: *"Can it be done without me forking the repository again?"* Yes, create a separate branch.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new branch, commit, then create a PR from that new branch. I'd suggest reverting to the HEAD of the upstream repo, not the head of your other patch.