# How to create 2 pull requests from the same fork

Tags: git, github

How to create 2 pull requests with different changes but in the same fork and at the same time?

I have tried to use the same branch, but the changes of the second PR are committed in the first one

Comment: The answer is in the question: Use different branches (: there is surely a duplicate for this question…

Comment: @AD7six https://stackoverflow.com/q/27790685/7976758 The title is almost exact dup. Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+two+pull+requests

Answer (score 0):

Note that a pull request is a "request to merge a branch into master/main". So if you want to create another pull request you just need to create an additional branch.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options:

1. Split changes into different branches locally, push the new branches and create the PRs.
2. Cherry-pick using Github's UI for cherry-picking (help [here](https://docs.github.com/en/desktop/contributing-and-collaborating-using-github-desktop/managing-commits/cherry-picking-a-commit))