# How to checkout a branch from repository

Tags: git

I have a repo called as 'color-palette ( https://github.com/3gwebtrain/color-palette.git) and it has other branches too.

I would like to clone one of the branch called `same-color` to my local system. But not working.

the command i used is :

`git checkout -b https://github.com/3gwebtrain/color-palette.git origin/same-color`

But this is not working. getting error as :

`fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git`

what is wrong here?

Comment: `git clone https://github.com/3gwebtrain/color-palette.git && cd color-palette && git checkout same-color`, as any tutorial would tell you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778088/how-to-clone-a-single-branch-in-git

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done with below single git command:

```
git clone https://github.com/3gwebtrain/color-palette.git -b same-color --single-branch
```

Comment: do you have any idea to specific commit id to merge with other branch?

Comment: You need to see [cherrypick](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick).
You can also see [What does cherry-picking a commit with git mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9339429/what-does-cherry-picking-a-commit-with-git-mean) and  [Git - Cherry pick a single commit for pull request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25955822/git-cherry-pick-a-single-commit-for-pull-request) . Its helps you.

Answer (score 4):

You don't clone just 1 branch of a git repo, you clone the repo, and then checkout that branch.

First clone it

```
git clone https://github.com/3gwebtrain/color-palette.git
```

then, in that folder, checkout the branch

```
git checkout same-color
```

You don't want to use `-b` option during checkout, because that creates a new branch

Comment: I didn't get the result. here is my try :

`
C:\Tutorials\try\testing>git clone https://github.com/3gwebtrain/color-palette.git
Cloning into 'color-palette'...
remote: Counting objects: 256, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (24/24), done.
Receiving objects:  87% (223/256), 332.01 KiB | 137.00 KiB/s   28R
Receiving objects: 100% (256/256), 431.63 KiB | 137.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (210/210), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
C:\Tutorials\try\testing>git checkout same-color
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
`

Comment: You want to do `cd color-pallete` after clone and before checkout, so that the checkout is done in the directory where the git lives

Comment: You can now clone just a single branch's history via `git clone --single-branch`. It is probably not generally recommended, but it is allowed.

Comment: @Mort that's neat. Do you know since which version exactly?

Comment: @TimCastelijns A quick web search reveals 1.7.10 https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gitster/git/master/Documentation/RelNotes/1.7.10.txt