# Clone Specific folder of git repository

Tags: git, github

I have my git repository on a server say X and it has below folder structure:
github --> Folder1
           Folder2
           Folder3

I want to clone this github on other server say Y, but only the Folder1.

Can someone help me out here?

Comment: You are looking for sparse checkout as explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13738951/978414).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any way to clone a git repository's sub-directory only?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/600079/is-there-any-way-to-clone-a-git-repositorys-sub-directory-only)

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37117086/how-to-checkout-a-branch-from-repository/37117425#37117425

Comment: I am able to do the same earlier, but if I change the file under folder1 say file1.sh then can we push that file to same folder folder1 only.