# git merge a cleaned-up repository

Tags: git

I have a software with a private git repository (hosted on my own server) with extensive history. At one point in time, the software was uploaded as a github repository *without its history*, as a clean repository. There were good reasons for doing so, which are not the point.

Now there are several pull requests that I would like to merge not just with the github repository, but also with the old private repository. If I can pull in the comments or even a reference to the github repository, that would be brilliant.

The private repository has not changed since the upload, so the PR should merge cleanly.

Comment: Clarification: I would probably do the cherry-picking on github. So all I need to merge with the private repository is the master branch of the github.

Answer (score 1):

You could add your public repo as a remote of your local cloned private repo and:

- fetch that public repo
- [cherry-pick one of its pull-request](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25955829/6309)

You can see another approach in "[Cherry pick a PR (pull request) from github](https://lalatendu.org/2015/12/02/cherry-pick-a-pr-pull-request-from-github/)", where you don't even need to fetch the public repo (using [`git am`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-am)):

For example you want to cherry pick https://github.com/fgrehm/vagrant-cachier/pull/164

> - Copy the pull request url, append “.patch” and open it in a browser.
>     e.g. https://patch-diff.githubusercontent.com/raw/fgrehm/vagrant-cachier/pull/164.patch
>     It will automatic resolve as something like below
>     https://patch-diff.githubusercontent.com/raw/fgrehm/vagrant-cachier/pull/164.patch
> - Use the new url for cherry picking the patch on your local repository

That is:

```
$ curl https://patch-diff.githubusercontent.com/raw/fgrehm/vagrant-cachier/pull/164.patch | git am
```

Comment: Thanks for the link to git am, I didn't know about that one.